# Session is not defined in Express

Tags: node.js, session, express

I've included the cookie-parser before the session (not sure if needed with the current versions), imported express-session as visible. If I change `session` to `express.session` on line 8 I get a deprecation error (not warning).

```
var express = require('express'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    expressSession = require('express-session'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: "yadayada",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.session);
    console.log(req.cookies);
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: This is a typo: you declared the variable using `expressSession` but use it as `session`, which most certainly will not work.

Answer (score 2):

`session` is not defined on line 9 because you have it declared as `expressSession` at the top i.e.

```
expressSession = require('express-session')
```

Either rename the declaration to `session` or update line 9 to call `expressSession` i.e.

```
app.use(expressSession({ ... }));
```

Answer (score 0):

same question......
but https://github.com/expressjs/session?_ga=1.45435812.1066105876.1451139756

```
app.use(session({
  genid: function(req) {
    return genuuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}))
```